# SUB TABLES WITH JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong in this? I am not getting the currect Percentage.
Q. Compute the revenue generated by each customer based on their orders. -Also, show each customer's revenue as a percentage of total revenue. Sort by customer name.

```
SELECT C.customerName, P1.customerNumber, SUM(P1.amount) AS REVENUE,( SUM(P1.amount)/SUM(P.S))*100 AS Percentage

FROM Customers C

JOIN Payments P1

 ON P1.customerNumber = C.customerNumber

 JOIN
 (
   SELECT customerNumber AS C1, SUM(amount) AS S
   FROM Payments
   GROUP BY customerNumber
 ) P

 ON P1.customerNumber=P.C1

 GROUP BY P1.customerNumber, C.customerName
 ORDER BY C.customerName;
```

Comment: `SUM(P.S)` in the output is obviously errorneous. You must use single value (and add it to GROUP BY).

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please provide sample data and table structure, preferably in a SQl FIddle like this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eKqDmiPuMaok7Uu3fwDKfD/1

Check if some of this queries suits your needs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       Customers.CustomerNumber,
       Customers.CustomerName,
       SUM(Payments.Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Customers.CustomerNumber) AS Revenue,
       (SUM(Payments.Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Customers.CustomerNumber) 
            / 
       SUM(Payments.Amount) OVER()) * 100 AS Percentage
FROM Customers
JOIN Payments ON Payments.CustomerNumber = Customers.CustomerNumber;
```

Or this:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerNumber,
       Customers.CustomerName,
       SUM(Payments.Amount) Revenue,
       (SUM(Payments.Amount)
            /
       (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
       FROM Payments)) * 100 Percentage
FROM Customers
JOIN Payments ON Payments.CustomerNumber = Customers.CustomerNumber
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerNumber,
         Customers.CustomerName
```